# Calling an Operator from an application handler

Tags: python, operator

I want to invoke an operator when rendering is finished.

```
import bpy

class FooOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "development.fooop"
    bl_label = "Foo"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls,context):
        return True

    def invoke(self,context,event):
        self.report({'INFO'},"running FooOp!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

def make_foo(scene):
    bpy.ops.development.fooop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(make_foo)
bpy.utils.register_class(FooOp)
```

When rendering finishes, this error message is printed to the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/reillyi/Dropbox/blender_dev/addons/render_notification/call_operator.blend/Text", line 16, in make_foo
  File "/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.71/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 186, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.development.fooop.poll() Missing 'window' in context
```

If I replace line 16, calling my FooOp operator, with

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add()
```

Then a torus is created with no problem.

Can you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only going to call this operator from the callback, you don't really need to use an operator.

However, the reason that your operator fails is that it doesn't support execution rather than invocation.

Add a method called `execute` with `(self, context)` as the arguments. If you want to use the `invoke()` method's code, just call `self.invoke` and pass `None` for the event (be careful with this). The `execute()` method should return a set for the result just as `invoke()` does, so if you're using invoke's body, just return the result of `self.invoke(context, None)`.

Finally, call the operator as `'EXEC_DEFAULT'` instead of `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'`

```
import bpy

class FooOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "development.fooop"
    bl_label = "Foo"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls,context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        return self.invoke(context, None)

    def invoke(self,context,event):
        self.report({'INFO'},"running FooOp!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

def make_foo(scene):
    bpy.ops.development.fooOp('EXEC_DEFAULT')


bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(make_foo)
bpy.utils.register_class(FooOp)
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason that I need an operator here is that I really want to run a _modal_ operator when rendering is done. However, when I try to do this, by modifying the `invoke` method to have `context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)`
   `return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}` and add a modal method `def modal(self,context,event):`   `return({'FINISHED','PASS_THROUGH'})` then blender segfaults! Any advice?

Comment: The question in this comment is now its own question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15841/running-modal-operator-from-callback-segfault