# Running Modal Operator from callback — segfault!

Tags: python, operator

This is a followup to the question [Calling an Operator from an application handler](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15540/calling-an-operator-from-an-application-handler/15541#15541).
I'm trying to start a modal operator running when rendering is finished, so I can capture the user's mouse and keyboard actions at that time.

I have this code:

```
import bpy

class FooOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "development.fooop"
    bl_label = "Foo"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls,context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        return self.invoke(context, None)

    def invoke(self,context,event):
        self.report({'INFO'},"running FooOp!")
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self,context,event):
        return({'FINISHED','PASS_THROUGH'})

def make_foo(scene):
    bpy.ops.development.fooop('EXEC_DEFAULT')

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(make_foo)
bpy.utils.register_class(FooOp)
```

When I run this script, and then render something, blender segfaults! Any insight?

By the way, if there were a better way to monitor the user's actions than a modal operator, that would also solve my problem.

Comment: The segfault comes from `context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)`. Even removing it I get errors that there is no window in context. It would appear that you have a limited context after rendering, maybe as it can run from the cli in the background. It looks like a model operator is not compatible with render_complete

Comment: There shouldn't be an `execute()` method, nor should you return multiple elements as a set in `invoke()`. The poll class method could be dropped. Is there any reason why you want to call an operator on `render_complete` and not just a plain function?